# Docker recreates directories on host after reboot

Tags: directory, docker, reboot, docker-compose, recreate

I created some containers on my system (ubuntu 14.04) using docker-compose which mounted directories from the host into the containers.
Now, every time I reboot the host, these directories are recreated, even though the containers do not longer exist (and I therefore deleted the directory).

Example:
I had a container for gitlab-ci in

```
/var/docker/gitlab-ci/
```

Containing the files/directories

```
docker-compose.yml
data/
postegresql/
```

I have deleted the directory

```
gitlab-ci/
```

now,

```
gitlab-ci/data
gitlab-ci/postgresql
```

are created after every reboot.
How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those containers might still exists. What does the `docker ps -a` command shows?

If you can still see your gitlab related containers, remove them with [`docker rm -f <container name>`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#rm), then delete the directories and reboot to check if they appear again.

If you still have your docker-compose.yml file, then you could have removed those containers with:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that the containers still existed.